# What does the Golden Pickaxe do?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

I received a Golden Pickaxe as a reward from a Tickington Sidequest in the Switch edition of Dragon Quest XI. It got sorted into my “Important Items” bag, so it’s not equipment, and it’s not a crafting item or consumable... but I’m not sure what it *is* for or does. The description in my inventory: **A tool that can turn even an ordinary mining expedition into a bullion bonanza!** isn’t very helpful either.

What’s this for?

Comment: Have you mined yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can reward you with an extra item whenever you "mine" those blue crystal structures. Take for example, the one outside of Hotto and the one near the Cryptic Crypt. Striking them will yield an additional ore.